# noConflict not working for jQuery 1.3 and 1.10

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use 2 differents versions of jQuery but it does not work as expected.

EDIT (let me explain a bit more what am I expecting).

Its a PHP Form which validates the labels (jQuery 1.10.2) and at the end, after the submit function, the div displays a "thank you" message with animation (jQuery 1.3.2) (on the save div, with ease animation)

Scripts used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqtransformplugin/jquery.jqtransform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="formValidator/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // set version 1.3.2 to variable and remove globals
    $jq132 = jQuery.noConflict(true); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/parsley.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/parsley.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I don't know if the problem comes from the compatibility with jQuery noConflict and the PHP file or I am missing something on the code.

Comment: var jq132 instead $jq132

Comment: What do you expect it to do? What does "doesn't work" mean? What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: After this change keeps working only one jquery version

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with PHP.

Comment: Updated content. By the way, h2ooooooo as I appreciate your answer, but if it could be a bit more constructive, would help the future users to know where the problem is.

Comment: @XaviAlsina There's no PHP code in this - hence PHP has nothing to do with it. If anything this is HTML and javascript, but it's really only javascript. It doesn't matter how the form is made.

Comment: But I mean I am working on a PHP file, so I dont know if for php files the methods must change or not. Anyway, thankyou for your time